# understanding lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have defined the lebesgue outer measure as $$\lambda(A) = \inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty (b_i - a_i) : A \subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i,b_i) \}$$

I am reading the proof for $\lambda [a,b] = b-a$. So far, I have shown that $\lambda [a,b] \geq b-a$ the notes then read: since $[a,b] \subset (a-\epsilon, b + \epsilon)$ we have that $\lambda [a,b] \leq b-a + 2 \epsilon$. I don't follow how this follows from the definition:

if I let $A = [a,b]$ then the definition reads as $$\lambda(A) = \inf \{ (b+\epsilon - a + \epsilon) : [a,b] \subset (a-\epsilon, b + \epsilon) \}$$ but I get this as equal to exactly $b - a + 2 \epsilon$. I am obviously misunderstanding the definition for $\lambda$ - could someone please explain

edit: so if that definition is wrong thenI don't follow the logic of his argument. We have that $$ \lambda [a,b] = \inf \{ \sum (b_i - a_i) : [a,b] \subset \cup_i^\infty (a_i,b_i) \}$$ then I don't understand where the $[a,b] \subset (a - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$ leads to the definition $\lambda[a,b] = b-a + 2\epsilon$?

Comment: Because $\lambda[a,b]$ is the infimum taken over all possible covers with intervals, then it must be less than or equal to the total length of any particular cover, in that case the particular cover is the interval $(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$

Comment: but it is the infimum of all of the sum of all possible covers, not all possible covers I thought?

Comment: I said it is the infimum **over** all possible covers (of something). What was your question again ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. I read $\lambda(A)$ as the infimum of the sum $\sum (b_i - a_i)$ where $A$ is covered by $\cup_i^\infty (b_i - a_i)$

Comment: Yes, what you wrote last is correct. And because $\lambda[a,b]$ is the infimum over **all** possible covers, then this infimum must be less than or equal to the total length of any particular cover of $[a,b]$. In your case, for a particular cover you take $(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$

Comment: Your second "definition" line: $\lambda(A) = \inf \{ (b+\epsilon - a + \epsilon) : [a,b] \subset (a-\epsilon, b + \epsilon) \}$ is not correct. The infimum on the right of this equality is greater than or equal to $\lambda[a,b]$, because this infimum is taken over a smaller set of covers, i.e covers of one exact type- covers of the type $(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$

Comment: Alright I see, there is one other thing I don't understand: The notes have written that $\lambda[a,b] \geq \lambda (a,b)$. I don't really follow this. We have that $(a,b) \subset [a,b]$ so surely, taking the infimum over a smaller set whill give that $\lambda (a,b) \geq \lambda [a,b]$?

Comment: No,because $(a,b)\subset [a,b]$ you can have more admissible covers of  $(a,b)$ and therefore, the infimum $\lambda(a,b)\leq \lambda[a,b]$. At least each cover of $[a,b]$ is also a cover of $(a,b)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36084/discussion-between-faceit-and-svetoslav).

Comment: $\lambda [a,b]=b-a+2\epsilon$ firstly is not a definition, and 2) you only have $\lambda[a,b]\leq b-a+2\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments the definition for the outer measure of $A=[a,b]$ is one, and it is $$\lambda(A) = \inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty (b_i - a_i) : A \subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i,b_i) \}\quad\quad (*)$$ and therefore $\lambda (A)$ is a fixed number.
So after this you can not say 
$$\lambda(A) = \inf \{ (b+\epsilon - (a-\epsilon)) : A \subset (a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon) \}$$
because this is the infimum over only a subset of all possible covers, i.e the covers which have the particular form $(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$, and therefore the above quantity is greater than or equal to $\lambda([a,b])$.

What  you can say after noticing that $[a,b]\subset (a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$ is that $(a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$ is an admissible element of the set over which the infimum in $(*)$ is taken. As such, by the definition of the infimum, you have that $\lambda(A)=\lambda([a,b])\leq (b+\epsilon-(a-\epsilon))=b-a+2\epsilon$

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to explain it to me.

Comment: You are welcome !